# Three.js show only point on obj file

Tags: three.js, textures, points

I have an .obj file.
I would like when this file load he show only points, no texture.
How can I do that?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: you don't want the faces either?

Comment: Hello, I only need the points for all obj.

Answer (score 0):

if your loaded mesh is named "mesh" do one of these:

```
var pg = mesh.geometry.clone();
var pointcloud = new THREE.Points(pg); // now use "pointcloud" instead of "mesh"
```

or

```
mesh.material.wireframe = true;
mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;  // and then just keep using the mesh
```

Comment: Hello, thank you but what I would like is this but with only points, because with your code he join the points between each other.

Comment: Yes I tried but the problem is that points are interconnecting.

Comment: That sounds like you are still drawing the (wireframe) mesh.  Just add the Points object to the scene, NOT the Mesh.